# HtmlWebpackPlugin with template adds an unwanted </html> at the end

Tags: webpack

My Webpack4 configuration almost works, but there is still one problem I can't figure out how to solve.

This is the webpack configuration:

```
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './resources/head-template.tpl',
            filename: './templates/head.tpl',
            hash: true,
            chunks : ['site'],
            inject: false,
            alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
        }),
```

My template goes more or less like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  (... more code...)

  <% for (var css in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) { %>
  <link href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[css] %>" rel="stylesheet">
  <% } %>

  (... more code...)

</head>
<!-- no /html here!!!-->
```

There is no `</html>` tag in my template file.

However, the final generated head.tpl DOES have a closing `</html>` . That file is meant to be embedded, so it should not have that tag.

Can I solve this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's embedded, could you remove the upper `<html>` tag too (as I assume that would be on the host page already), then it shouldn't auto close the tag.

Comment: Oops. I did not think about that. Such a simple solution. Thanks :)